# Assign teacher role to particular users - Moodle

Tags: roles, moodle, assign

I'm trying to assign a user as a teacher in a course. but i want him to be a teacher only for particular students in the course. lets say i have 10 student enrolled in the course. and i want one of them to be teacher only to 3 students. is it possible?

Comment: It most certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups to group users together, so have the teacher and the students in the same group - https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Groups

Edit the course settings, scroll down to the group settings, change the group mode and save the course.

Then on the course management menu go to users -> groups and create a group for each teacher.